# IIS URL Rewrite - Page Forward

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I've been messing around with a URL rewrite for a bit now, however, I can't get it work despite going through the documentation - so it's probably just my lack of knowledge on them.

I have the following URL:

```
www.testsite.company.com/tasks
```

I however want to forward any request to this URL to:

```
www.testsite.company.com/tasks/dashboard
```

How would I accomplish this using IIS URL Rewrite rules?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the below rule:

```
 <rule name="Forward rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/tasks/$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/tasks/dashboard" />
            </rule>
```

[image]